# Concat param name to loop over params

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a procedure that accepts multiple varchar(4000) params (26 of them).

Each of them is a comma-separated string of values.

Once they are passed in, I would like to break each of the strings apart and insert them into a temp table for use later in the proc.

I'd prefer not to write a statement that processes each parameter individually, but rather write a while loop that relies on a counter to loop over each parameter and process each one in turn. Currently, I've tried the following, but its not correct.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc] (
    @string1 varchar(4000) = null;
    @string2 varchar(4000) = null;
    @string3 varchar(4000) = null;
    ....declare @string4 -> @string25...
    @string26 varchar(4000) = null;)

CREATE TABLE #emails (
    address varchar(80)
     )

Set @counter = 1

WHILE @counter < 27
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #emails(address) SELECT element as address from FT_SPLIT_LIST(isNull('@string'+convert(varchar,@counter),''),',')
SET @counter = @counter +1
END

SELECT * FROM #emails
```

Currently, this is not returning a table with all the CSVs from @string1 -> @string26.

FT_SPLIT_LIST works- I use it in many other places. I just need to know if there is a way to dynamically declare the parameter that is being passed in to it?

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to accomplish without writing a statement for each of the @string1->@string27 parameters?

Thanks,
C

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What do you have _loading_ those parameters?  This is almost certainly the 'wrong' way to do this is in the first place.  @Oded's answer looks like it should be good; if that doesn't work, you could see about loading the data into a temp table via `LOAD` (I think, maybe `IMPORT`?) and then doing a single batch update from there.

Comment: Oded, Thanks for the response. I'll look in to the link you posted. In this case, I am constrained by the system I am integrating with. The string parameters are being passed in to the database via the web API, and as a result I am required to pass in the params as Varchar(4000), and in chunks. I'd much prefer to pass the content in as XML, but that isn't possible via the systems API. My constraint is that the data has to come in the way it is currently coming in. Given that I have that, is there a suggestion on how to take multiple CSV strings, and iterate over them to insert them in a table?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 and above have [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx):

> Table-valued parameters are declared by using user-defined table types. You can use table-valued parameters to send multiple rows of data to a Transact-SQL statement or a routine, such as a stored procedure or function, without creating a temporary table or many parameters.

These are a much better option than comma delimited varchars and `FT_SPLIT_LIST`.

I suggest reading [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2008 Using Table-Valued Parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog for a comprehensive discussion on this topic.

Comment: Oded, Thanks for the response. I will definitely look in to the link you posted.

Comment: +1 I came here to post about TVPs... definitely the preferred method to looping over CSVs....